# How to make IntelliJ IDEA run tests with -ea JVM option

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

I couldn't find such an option in `Run/Debug Configurations` -> `Templates` -> `JUnit`.

[image: Run/Debug Configurations]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `-ea` to the **VM options** of the active run/debug configuration. Add it to the Template JUnit configuration as well so that all the new configurations inherit this default (it should be already like this out of the box unless you've modified the template configuration).

[image: current]

[image: template]